# Creating a method with an array that fills a checkerboard pattern

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting to write a program that fills an 8x8 checkerboard with two alternating colors, but I am struggling in creating a method `public void fillCheckerboard(Color[][] board)` to test it.

I'm trying to print out an array that shows 'x' for black and 'x' for white.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask].

Comment: Do you mean _'x' for black and 'o' for white_?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: "I'm trying to do *x* but am having trouble" is a *story*, not a question. What's your question? And what code were you trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modulo 2 of the sum of x and y to get this checker pattern. Hereby some example code which populates a two dimensional array to do so. Any questions just let me know.

```
public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String []args){
             String[][] board = new String[8][8];

         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                 board[i][j] = (i + j) % 2 == 0 ? "X" : "O";
             }
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                 System.out.print(board[i][j]+" ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         }
     }
}
```

It will give you an input like you would most likely want:

```
X O X O X O X O 
O X O X O X O X 
X O X O X O X O 
O X O X O X O X 
X O X O X O X O 
O X O X O X O X 
X O X O X O X O 
O X O X O X O X
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
private static class Color {
    private final char c;

    public Color(char c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + c;
    }
}

public static final Color WHITE = new Color('X');
public static final Color BLACK = new Color(' ');

public void fillCheckerboard(Color[][] board) {
    Color c = BLACK;
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = c;
            c = c == BLACK ? WHITE : BLACK;
        }
    }
}
```